# Distributed execution under eager mode using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, eager-execution, distributed-tensorflow

According to a recently published [white paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01855) and the [RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/20) on GitHub, tensorflow eager currently supports distributed execution. It is mentioned that, similar to the graph mode, we can run an operation eagerly on a remote device by setting the device name as, for example, "/job:training/task:2/device:GPU:0". However, I can't find any code examples or tutorials on how to do it.

I do note that there are plenty of tutorials on [tf.distribute](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute), a high-level API for distributed training, which supports both graph and eager mode. However, I am more interested in how tf.distribute works **under the hood** for the eager mode. Specifically, I would like to know:

1. How to connect a client to a remote server under eager mode?
2. When and how is the cluster definition specified under eager mode?

I would be grateful if someone could provide answers to those questions. Thanks!